# Cannot set 'socket' property of udpsink gstreamer element in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, udp, media, gstreamer

When I setup and start the pipeline I get:

'Could not get/set settings from/on resource' from the bus

Code:

```
...
// create UDP sink
udpsink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");
assert (udpsink != NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (udpsink), "socket", gsocket, NULL);

// add and link gstreamer elements and then start the pipeline
...
```

Notice that once I remove the g_object_set() or I use it to set another property (like 'async' for instance) everything works fine. Could it be that 'socket' property has any issues specifically in iOS? Keep in mind that the exact same code works fine in Linux.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks

P.S. Notice that I'm using the official iOS bundle of GStreamer (i.e. GStreamer.framework) downloaded from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.4.4/ and have tried to follow the conventions of the sample code at http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/xcode%20iOS

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (udpsink), "socket",G_TYPE_SOCKET, gsocket, NULL);
```

instead of

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (udpsink), "socket", gsocket, NULL);
```